# How to test constructor calls from a cdn imported package

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I am writing tests for tesseract ocr package. Problem is the packege was imported into the react index.html using cdn(`<script src='https://unpkg.com/tesseract.js@v2.0.0-alpha.10/dist/tesseract.min.js'></script>`). Having to test this, I can't find it in either global(global.tesseract) or window (window.tesseract). How do I get this package into my test file as I keep getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'TesseractWorker' of undefined.

I need to be able to find this package and test this file

```
import getDetails from '../getDetails';

describe('getDetails() function', () => {
  const file = {
    name: 'image.png',
  };
  const response = { data: {} };

   const { TesseractWorker } = window.Tesseract;
  const worker = new TesseractWorker();

  it('should return ticket details', async () => {
    worker ({
      recognize: jest.fn(() => ({
        progress: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({
          text:: `An updated look at all the ways that autonomous vehicles will change our lives in profound ways.`
 }))
      }))
    });
```

Comment: check the global variable also try  `const  TesseractWorker  = window.Tesseract;`

Comment: @ShireeshaParampalli, that did not work